# Why is the stream being closed when using Scala Using

Tags: java, scala

I am writing some tests for a function which loads a CSV via a function `readIntoList` using a BufferSource.

```scala
class CSV(source: BufferedSource) {

  def readIntoList: List[List[Any]] = {
    lazy val lines = Using.resource(source) { x => x.getLines.zipWithIndex }
    println(source)
    val columns = for {
      (line, index: Int) <- lines
    } yield {
      val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
      val row = cols(0)
      if (index == 0) List("Index", row)
      else List(index, row)
    }
    columns.toList
  }
}
```

Loading the source with a string works fine.

```
val singleRowCSV =
          """TotalSpend
            |111
            |""".stripMargin
val csv = new CSV(
    new BufferedSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(singleRowCSV.getBytes()))
)
```

However calling the function using `Source.fromURL` and providing a CSV on the file system.

```
val resource = getClass.getResource("/10_rows.csv")
val csv = new CSV(Source.fromURL(resource))
```

Causes `java.io.IOException: Stream closed`

It was my understanding that Using will automatically close the stream for me, so now I am wondering where the stream is being closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `Using` do - it's the equivalent of Java's try with resources:

```
try (Resource resource = initialize()) {
  // use resource
} // once you leave this block resource is guaranteed to be .close()ed
```

This is basically a solution to make sure `.close()` is always called once you exit the block, whether you just return a value normally or throw exception.

If you don't want your resources to be closed here, don't wrap them with `Using` here, but in the place that should be responsible for managing the resource's lifecycle.

In your code you have:

```
Using.resource(source) { x => x.getLines.zipWithIndex }
```

which means that resource is closed once you leave this block. However, `.getLines` might be evaluated lazily so when you start evaluating it once the stream is closed you'll get an exception, so you can try making the call eager to avoid it:

```
// easier, but I wouldn't recommend that for large files
Using.resource(source) { x => x.getLines.zipWithIndex.toList } // closed here
```

or you can just perform whole operation inside `Using`:

```
  def readIntoList: List[List[Any]] = {
    // actually you should acquire resource here as well so I would suggest
    // source: () => BufferedSource
    Using.resource(source()) { resource =>
      lazy val lines = resource.getLines.zipWithIndex
      println(resource)
      val columns = for {
        (line, index: Int) <- lines
      } yield {
        val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
        val row = cols(0)
        if (index == 0) List("Index", row)
        else List(index, row)
      }
      columns.toList
    } // closed here
  }
```